# Enable draggable and droppable on dynamically created elements jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I want to automatically enable 'draggable' and 'droppable' on dynamically created elements. I DON'T want to just reinitialize it after I add the element to the DOM.

For example:

```
$('static_element_such_as_body').on('event', 'dynamicElement', function(){ 
    console.log('yayyyy'); 
});
```

That is a truely dynamic event handler. How can I impliment the 'draggable' and 'droppable' to the .on or .live binder?

There is the code I'm using for drag and droppable:

```
    $('.draggable').draggable({
        helper: function() { //helper function is used to duplicate the event dragged


            return $('<p>winning</p>').append($(this).find('.name').clone()); //Idk what class or where .name is but without it, it bombs out
        },
        stack: ".draggable", //this changes our z index to be the upper most
        start: function(event, ui) { //this fires on start
            c.tr        = this; //set up our c cariable
            c.helper    = ui.helper;
        }
    }).droppable({ //this let's us know this element is droppable
        drop: function(event, ui) { //when you actually drop
            $(c.helper).remove();
        },
        over: function (event, ui) { //called when we are hovering over a droppable element with this selector
            console.log('over');
        },
        out: function(event, ui){
            console.log('left');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently no one knows so I figured out a more 'automated' solution. Instead of manually re-initializing it once you add the element, you can use this event handler to automate that re-initializing for you.

```
$mainContainer.on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e){
    if($.inArray('relatable', e.target.classList) != -1){
        drag_drop_init();
        if(helper_bool_isRelatableEnabled){
            drag_drop_enable();
        }else{
            drag_drop_disable();
        }
    }
});
```

Where $mainContainer is a static element, such as $('body'), and 'relatable' is the name of the class that I use to know this element should allow drag and droppable. It's the class I use to initialize ie: $('.relatable').draggable()